# Extract day/night resources from Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar

Tags: material-design, android-theme

I'm using `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` as my app's theme and would like to programmatically get, for example, the `android.R.attr.textColorPrimary` color for both dark mode and light mode. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ColorInt
fun getStyledDayNightColor(context: Context, @AttrRes attrResId: Int, night: Boolean): Int {
    val configuration = Configuration(context.resources.configuration).apply {
        uiMode = if (night) {
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
        } else {
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO
        }
    }
    val contextWrapper = ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents_DayNight).apply {
        applyOverrideConfiguration(configuration)
    }
    val ta = contextWrapper.obtainStyledAttributes(intArrayOf(attrResId))
    return ta.getColor(0, Color.GREEN).also {
        ta.recycle()
    }
}
```